# WatchFace sample - how to run

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sample

I imported WatchFace sample https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace
however I cannot run phone app neither install watch faces to the emulator.
That sample project's phone app doesn't have default activity, but when I'm trying to start any of it's activities, it gives Null exception on ComponentName

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.android.wearable.watchface.DigitalWatchFaceCompanionConfigActivity.onCreate(DigitalWatchFaceCompanionConfigActivity.java:77)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
```

row 77 is the last one in the onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_digital_watch_face_config);

    mPeerId = getIntent().getStringExtra(WatchFaceCompanion.EXTRA_PEER_ID);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .build();

    ComponentName name = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(
            WatchFaceCompanion.EXTRA_WATCH_FACE_COMPONENT);
    TextView label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
    label.setText(label.getText() + " (" + name.getClassName() + ")");
}
```

I set wearable app to not running any activity so it should install watch faces to the emulator. However is does not install anything.

I hope this is not a totally broken sample and I am just doing something very wrong, just can figure out what?
 Simple "hello world" app works OK and install with no issues when running on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved. This was basically some kind of emulator or/and Studio glitch. I deleted old Wearable emulator, created a new one and connected it to a phone. Right after everything installed normally.